# Gmail in Chrome: how to disable the Cmd (or Ctrl) + Enter shortcut for sending

Tags: google-chrome, email, gmail

I have searched for disabling the Cmd+Enter shortcut (or Ctrl+Enter sous Windows) for sending the composed email in Gmail in Chrome, but did not find any solutions.

Hope that somebody can help. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Yeah, this has caused me to prematurely send so many emails as I am copying/pasting and adding spaces/new lines...

Answer (score 1):

According to this page: (official help) https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?hl=en

Some shortcuts are always on. Including Cmd + Enter. It seems you cannot turn it off.

Btw I found this help page from Gmail Settings > General tab > Keyboard shortcuts section,
"Learn more" link next to the radio buttons to turn shortcuts on or off.
The help page seems to be the authoritative doc.

Comment: Thanks. Obviously I had already seen that help page. I posted the question hoping somebody here can have some hacking solutions to do that, for example overriding that shortcut with an action of the system or the browser. I came across a solution for Safari but that one is not applicable to Chrome :(

Comment: That wasn't obvious at all. It would have been very useful if you have included this in your question and specified that you're looking for a hack.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to avoid that an email is send too early, this may help:

https://gmail.googleblog.com/2009/03/new-in-labs-undo-send.html

It gives you some time to react and pull it back.

Comment: this is in the first "General" settings tab now.

Comment: A trick I use for emails that I don't to be sent prematurely is to add an email address `xyz` to the recipients list.  Gmail will barf and not send when it sees an incorrectly formatted email address. The fallback - if I haven't remembered to do that - is clicking on Undo within a few seconds.  The annoying thing is that in Gmail, `Ctrl-Enter` in the body of an email sends it, `Shift-Enter` inserts a newline.  In Google Sheets `Ctrl-Enter` in the cell editor inserts a newline, `Shift-Enter` moves up one cell, so I always get caught when swapping between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this thread is 9 years old, I'm re-solving this problem.

I found some tampermonkey scripts that didn't work anymore in 2024. So I wrote a new one that works for me again.

https://gist.github.com/PatrickvEk/c942b0e2bb0b9f9d34b33820aab07ec5#file-disable-gmail-cmd-enter-2024-user-js